# Greek letters in ggraph nodes in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggraph

When I run the R script below in RStudio, the theta is shown correctly.

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
```

# Greek letters
```{r ggraph}
nodes<-data.frame(label=c("θ","S"))
edges<-data.frame(from=c(2),to=c(1))
graph<-tbl_graph(nodes=nodes,edges=edges)
ggraph::ggraph(graph,layout="fr")+
    ggraph::geom_edge_link()+
    ggraph::geom_node_label(mapping = aes(label=label))     
```
````

But when I knit it, I get this error message (partly in Danish):

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character θ (U+03B8)
>   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using
>   pdflatex. For R Markdown users, see
>   https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html Fejl: LaTeX
>   failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging
>   for debugging tips. See test.log for more info. In addition:
>   Advarselsbeskeder: 1: I grid.Call(C_textBounds,
>   as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i
>   'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  2: I grid.Call(C_textBounds,
>   as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i
>   'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  3: I grid.Call(C_textBounds,
>   as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i
>   'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  4: I grid.Call(C_textBounds,
>   as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i
>   'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  5: I
>   grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
>   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i 'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  6:
>   I grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
>   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i 'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  7:
>   I grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
>   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i 'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for  8:
>   I grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
>   konverteringsfejl på 'θ' i 'mbcsToSbcs': punktum erstattet for 
>   Kørsel stoppet

I have tried using expression(theta) instead of the character itself, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way to solve this, but one way is to overcome your issue is to the following:

1. Use `xelatex` and the `fontenc` package;
2. force `dev` to `"jpeg"`, `"png"` or "`cairo_pdf`" to generate figures (`θ` can cause issue with other devices).

Below in the RMarkdown document I've used

````
    ---
    title: "test"
    header_includes:
        - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    output:
        pdf_document:
          latex_engine: xelatex
    ---


    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
     knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, dev = "png", dpi = 300)
     library(tidygraph)
     library(ggraph)
     ```

    # Greek letters

    ```{r ggraph}
    library(ggraph)
    library(ggplot2)
    nodes<-data.frame(label=c("θ","S"))
    edges<-data.frame(from=c(2),to=c(1))
    graph<-tbl_graph(nodes=nodes,edges=edges)
    ggraph::ggraph(graph,layout="fr")+
        ggraph::geom_edge_link()+
        ggraph::geom_node_label(mapping = aes(label=label))
    ```
````

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple solution! I would like to find a way to make it work independent of latex version - I am using greek letters in ggraph in a package I am developing. But this will work, and I can add instructions in the help documents.

Comment: I tested your solution with "cairo_pdf" instead of "png", and that worked as well. Then the text in the figures get searchable.

Comment: I will add this in post as an eddit!